# Is there an hamiltonian formulation of $D_p$-brane theory?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, branes

I'm aware that the dynamics of $D_p$-branes can be studied using the [DBI action](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Dirac-Born-Infeld+action):
$$S_{DBI}=-T_p\int d^{p+1}\xi\sqrt{-\det(g_{\alpha\beta})}$$
(with external fields set to zero). I'd like to know whether **there is a hamiltonian formulation for this dynamics** because, since the Lagrangian isn't in a standard form, I wouldn't know how to derive a formula for the Hamiltonian.

For context, I'm interested in a hamiltonian formulation because I want to study energy constraints on a brane configuration, and knowing the Hamiltonian would be helpful.

Comment: This looks relevant: https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.06036 , https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.14412

Comment: @Qmechanic does eq. (6) of the linked paper imply that the Hamiltonian is zero if the external fields are set to zero?